# Bash command "script" printing Script started stopped timing in log file. Is there a way to exclude the log?

Tags: bash

I'm executing script command to capture the logs in a file using --quiet option. However it still adds "Script started on" logs to file which i do not want to get logged.
Is there a way to exclude the log? One option could be to trim the lines from file which start with "Script started" text

Command example

```
script -a -f --quiet ~/script.log
```

File content

```
Script started on 2024-01-17 10:06:32+00:00 [TERM="xterm-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/16"
```

Comment: Please be more specific. OS Version, shell version, etc. What type of script? bash? zsh? Python?